# How to pass complex object as parameter in apps script function call

Tags: google-apps-script, function-call

lets assume that i have the following code:

```
  
  //get corresponding spreadsheet
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // alle sheets im doc ermitteln
  var sheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();

  // startSheet festlegen
  var startSheet = sheets[1];
```

how do i pass the complex apps script object "startSheet" to a function like myDumbFunction(startSheet) ?

Currently in the function the passed parameter behaves like a string. No parameters in it, no function calls available.

And i know that there would be the option to use global variables. but i want to pass as function-parameter

I tried to pass complex object as function parameter. non complex object was passed to function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it directly. I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Example code for reference :-

```
function myFuntion1() {
 //get corresponding spreadsheet
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // alle sheets im doc ermitteln
  var sheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();

  // startSheet festlegen
  var startSheet = sheets[0];

  myFunction2(startSheet);
}

function myFunction2(sheet) {
// You can use the sheet object
...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when i try to call f.e. sheet.getRange(x,y) in myFunction2, it says, that getRange() is undefined

Comment: How many sheets are present in your spreadsheet? If there's only one and you want that, then use sheets[0] in the code instead of sheets[1]. Updated the code.

Comment: The document has 6 sheets, so the startSheet is surely not null. When i call (in myFunction1()) startSheet.getRange(x,y) right before the call  myFunction2(startSheet) everything is fine. in myFunction2 something is getting passed, but this is just not the complex AppsScript sheet-object

Comment: That's wierd. Can you paste your function2 code in the question?

Comment: ok, really strange, nothing changed, now i get the object and can access getRange() !?! thanks for your help

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. Did you ever figure out how to get it working?

Comment: Can you tell me what's different in your code compared to the posted answer?